# Find out Сompositor node tree active output (Python)

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes

Let's say for some reason I have 5 "Composite" nodes in Compositor. How can I find out through API which one of them is active render output?

`bpy.context.scene.node_tree.active_output` seems to always return -1, and this is not a node index as it might seem. `len(bpy.context.scene.node_tree.outputs)` seems to always return 0. `bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['Composite']` has no attribute like `is_active_output`. `bpy.context.scene.node_tree` has no attribute like `get_active_output`. So is it possible? Or maybe it works in some other way?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be exposed to the API. Workaround might be muting each node to determine the active one. Any reason why you have to add multiple output nodes?

Comment: Thank you, I was just going to do it that way if there's no other solution. The reason is I want to get link from user's node setup to active output and replace it with addon's setup. And if user for some strange reason added several Composite nodes and connected different links to them, the script wouldn't be able to decide the link to which Composite node should be replaced. On the other hand now I start to think that it doesn't matter so much because who am I to prevent user's mistakes: the addon should replace just all links to all Composites with its results. Checkmate! )) Thanks again!